# jQuery doesn't display specific hidden content when I use the .show() command

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my HTML and jQuery code. jQuery displays the hidden elements, except for the `#image4` and `#video4` elements, which stay hidden with if I select `image` or `video`. All the other elements get displayed correctly.

Any idea why those two won't show?

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var fields = jQuery('#image_type');
        var select = this.value;
        fields.change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'image') {
              alert($(this).val());
                $('#images_pop_up').show();
                $('#video1').hide();
                $('#video2').hide();
                $('#video3').hide();
                $('#video4').hide();
                $('#image1').show();
                $('#image2').show();
                $('#image3').show();
                $('#image4').show();
                $(' #image5').show();
              }
              else {
                $('#images_pop_up').show();
                $('#image1').hide();
                $('#image2').hide();
                $('#image3').hide();
                $('#image4').hide();
                $('#image5').hide();
                $('#video1').show();
                $('#video2').show();
                $('#video3').show();
                $('#video4').show();
                $('#image5').show();
              }

        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="images_pop_up" style="display:none;">
   <span id="image1"  style="display:none;" ><img src="/uploads/commerce/images/large/easton-163135-wheeled-bag.jpg" border="0" alt="easton-163135-wheeled-bag.jpg" title=" easton-163135-wheeled-bag.jpg " class="productimage"><input type="hidden" name="products_previous_image_lrg" value="easton-163135-wheeled-bag.jpg"><br>Nice bag</span>
   <span  id ="video1" style="display:none;"></span></td>
   <td  class="textSmall" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <span id="image3"  style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="products_previous_image_lrg" value="easton-163135-wheeled-bag.jpg"><input type="hidden" name="products_previous_image_lrg_caption" value="Nice bag"></span>
            <span id ="video3"><input type="hidden" name="products_previous_video_embed"><input type="hidden" name="products_previous_video_embed_caption"></span>
            <td class="textSmall" valign="top"><span id="image4" style="display:none;">New Image File: <input type="text" name="products_image_lrg" value="easton-163135-wheeled-bag.jpg"><br>Image Caption: <input type="text" name="products_image_lrg_caption" value="Nice bag"></span>
               <span id ="video4" style="display:none;">Video Embed field: <input type="text" name="products_video_embed"><br>Video Image Caption: <input type="text" name="products_video_embed_caption"></span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="image5" style="display:none;"> <a href='#' onclick='return false;'><img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_select.gif" border="0" alt="Select" title=" Select " onclick="popupWindowSelectImg('./images_select.php?imgSize=lrg&inpt=products_image_lrg&div=div_img_lrg&width=200&height=30','lrg','products_image_lrg','div_img_lrg');"></a></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
               <div id='div_img_lrg'></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</div>
```

Comment: It could be because parent is hidden or duplicate IDs or etc... You should try to replicate your issue on jsfiddle

Comment: There are a couple of strange spaces in your html and also one in you jquery code. It should be id="" not id ="". I think that might affect the end result. Please try to clean that up first

Comment: In both `if` and `else`, you do `$("#image5").show()`. The previous `$("#image5").hide()` in the `else` has no effect..

Comment: Is `select` not a reserved word?

Comment: @3rror404: No. It's a valid variable name.

Comment: it still doesn't work ..

Comment: it's image4 and video4 that have issues .. they stay hidden ...

Comment: @user3267381 Can you reproduce the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: You have invalid HTML. A `<span>` isn't a valid child of a `<tr>`, and a `<td>` can't be a child of a `<div>`. Overall, the code is just a mess

Comment: How can I hide those options then ?

Comment: Before you concern yourself with JavaScript, you need to fix your HTML.

Comment: This is what I'm asking about ... if I can not have the HTML that way , how can I hide image4 and video4 within the same cell so that I can either show video4 or image4 depending on what i select

Comment: If you can't have valid HTML, you can't guarantee that your JavaScript will work. Why can't you have valid HTML?

Comment: @user3267381 You could have a `td` containing 2 `div`s, each of those containing a video, then show/hide the `div`s. One of many possibilities.

Comment: @Jason I thought span shouldn't matter .. I have two span within the td .. and the span in other tds are working .. very confusing

Comment: Using a span instead of a div there shouldn't matter, but you have lots of invalid html, so all bets are off.

Comment: @JasonP All the tags have their matching closing tags .. I'm confused about what is referred to as invalid HTML .. any hint ?

Comment: cookie monster posted a comment with a few of the issues.

Comment: I was dealing with the wrong file with the same name .. I was about to fix it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var fields = jQuery('#image_type');
    var select = this.value;
    $('#image_type').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'image') {
            alert($(this).val());
            $("[id^=image]").show();
            $("[id^=video]").hide();
        } else {
            $("[id^=video]").show();
            $("[id^=image]").hide();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: still not working .. image4,video$ ideas not showing

Answer (score 1):

What sticks out most to me is that you're copy pasting when you could be putting CSS to work for you by giving them all the same class (or the appropriate groups of elements the same class at least) and then hiding and showing them based on that.

Your bug is probably caused by a slight typo somewhere in the selectors or the place where you're setting the ids in the markup.